# FFMPEG/tensorflow warping .mp4's with no observable pattern of correlation

Tags: python, tensorflow, video, ffmpeg, gif

The function that performs the processing is here:

```
def ffwd_video(path_in, path_out, checkpoint_dir, device_t='/gpu:0', batch_size=4):
video_clip = VideoFileClip(path_in, audio=False)
video_writer = ffmpeg_writer.FFMPEG_VideoWriter(path_out, video_clip.size, video_clip.fps, codec="libx264",
                                                preset="slow", bitrate="3000k",
                                                audiofile=path_in, def ffwd_video(path_in, path_out, checkpoint_dir, device_t='/gpu:0', batch_size=2):threads=None,
                                                ffmpeg_params=None)

g = tf.Graph()
soft_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
soft_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
with g.as_default(), g.device(device_t), \
        tf.Session(config=soft_config) as sess:

    batch_shape = (batch_size, video_clip.size[1], video_clip.size[0], 3)
    print(batch_shape)
    img_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=batch_shape,
                                     name='img_placeholder')

    preds = transform.net(img_placeholder)
    print(preds)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    if os.path.isdir(checkpoint_dir):
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        else:
            raise Exception("No checkpoint found...")
    else:
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_dir)

    X = np.zeros(batch_shape, dtype=np.float32)

    def style_and_write(count):
        for i in range(count, batch_size):
            X[i] = X[count]  # Use last frame to fill X
        _preds = sess.run(preds, feed_dict={img_placeholder: X})
        for i in range(0, count):
            video_writer.write_frame(np.clip(_preds[i], 0, 255).astype(np.uint8))

    frame_count = 0  # The frame count that written to X
    for frame in video_clip.iter_frames():
        X[frame_count] = frame
        frame_count += 1
        if frame_count == batch_size:
            style_and_write(frame_count)
            frame_count = 0

    if frame_count != 0:
        style_and_write(frame_count)

    video_writer.close()
```

I do not expect this to be a repeatable sample as it requires gigabytes of models/checkpoints/etc. to do so.

Anyways, I am converting .gif's to .mp4's using this line of code:

`os.system('echo "y"| ffmpeg -i temp.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" temp.mp4')`

and when I run a subsequent .mp4 through the video rendering function, this will sometimes happen:

original: https://i.imgur.com/WrBa6yw.gifv

result: https://giphy.com/gifs/dream-bot-BzqB8XILJuVTJcgJnn

It will happen on certain .mp4's 100% of the time and on others, 0% of the time. It either happens to a clip or it does not happen to that clip. It is not a case of a single clip sometimes having this problem. If it is good, it is always good but if it's bad, that clip will never work.

After this output data from when the clips are processed:

```
good gifs
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 728x728, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
frame=  450 fps= 78 q=-1.0 Lsize=    7570kB time=00:00:14.93 bitrate=4152.6kbits/s

Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 800x450, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 728x408, q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc
frame=  360 fps=198 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2568kB time=00:00:14.93 bitrate=1408.8kbits/s 

Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 728x408, 23.92 fps, 23.98 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 728x408, q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc
frame=  360 fps=198 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2568kB time=00:00:14.93 bitrate=1408.8kbits/s 

bad gifs
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 800x450, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
frame=  150 fps= 87 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1840kB time=00:00:05.92 bitrate=2545.8kbits/s

Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 378x275, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 378x274, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
frame=  115 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     253kB time=00:00:04.52 bitrate= 459.4kbits/s
```

I have noticed that the `frame=` value is exactly 15x larger than the .gif fps value while for the bad .gifs, it is not. I believe this is the cause but do not know how to change these values. does anybody know how I can process/convert the gif to .mp4 so that the `frame=` value is 15x the gif fps?